# 4min Timeout problem of HTTP Trigger of Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

I have P1v2 instance of Azure Function. I have Python running on Docker.

I have Azure Data Factory calling Azure Function with Trigger.

Data Factory get error of timeout since heavy data process of Functions takes more than 4min.

Is there workaround for HTTP trigger timeout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTTP triggered function *always* times out after 230 seconds because of the Azure Load Balancer.

> Regardless of the function app timeout setting, 230 seconds is the maximum amount of time that an HTTP triggered function can take to respond to a request. This is because of the **default idle timeout of Azure Load Balancer**. For longer processing times, consider using the [Durable Functions async pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview#async-http) or [defer the actual work and return an immediate response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/performance-reliability#avoid-long-running-functions).

Source: [Azure Functions hosting options - Function app timeout duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#timeout)